# Reverse array (starting from the character) and save it in the original string

Tags: c

This what I do in code:
Program that read a String input, then call the function reverse2nPart, that receives the string and the read character. The function reverses the content of the second part of the string, (starting from the taken character) and saves it in the original string.  Print the second character using pointer of the reversed string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse2nPart(char *str, char ch) {
    // Find the index of the specified character in the string
    char *chPos = strchr(str, ch);

    if (chPos != NULL) {
        // Calculate the length of the second part of the string
        int secondPartLen = strlen(chPos);

        // Reverse the second part of the string and save it in the original string
        for (int i = 0; i < secondPartLen / 2; i++) {
            char temp = chPos[i];
            chPos[i] = chPos[secondPartLen - 1 - i];
            chPos[secondPartLen - 1 - i] = temp;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    char inputString[100];
    char ch;

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s", inputString);

    printf("Enter the character to substring the string: ");
    scanf(" %c", &ch); // Use a space before %c to consume the newline character

    reverse2nPart(inputString, ch);

    printf("The reversed string is: %s\n", inputString);

    // Find the position of the specified character in the reversed string

        printf("The second character in the new reversed string is: %c\n", *(inputString+1));

    return 0;
}
```

The screen (inputs&outputs) looks like this because my code doesn't save it in original input:

```
Enter a string: abc123@gmail.com
Enter the character to substring the string: @
The reversed string is: abc123moc.liamg@
The second character in the new reversed string is: b
```

the screen should look like this instead:

```
Enter a string: abc123@gmail.com
Enter the character to substring the string: @
The reversed string is: moc.liamg@
The second character in the new reversed string is: o
```

Comment: What if the char was not found?

Answer (score 2):

I use some more functions.
If the string was not found I decided to return NULL to indicate the error.

```
char *reverse(char *str)
{
    char *end = str, *saved = str;

    if(str && *str)
    {
        while(*(end + 1)) end++;
        while(end > str) 
        {
            char tmp = *str;
            *str++ = *end;
            *end-- = tmp;
        }
    }
    return saved;
}

char *reverseFromChar(char *str, char ch)
{
    if(str)
    {
        while(*str && *str != ch) str++;
        if(*str) reverse(str);
        else str = NULL;
    }
    return str;
}


int main(void)
{
    char *result;
    printf("reversed: '%s'\n", (result = reverseFromChar((char[]){"abc123@gmail.com"}, '@')) ? result : "NULL");
    printf("reversed: '%s'\n", (result = reverseFromChar((char[]){"abc123@gmail.com"}, 'b')) ? result : "NULL");
    printf("reversed: '%s'\n", (result = reverseFromChar((char[]){"abc123@gmail.com"}, 'Z')) ? result : "NULL");
    printf("reversed: '%s'\n", (result = reverseFromChar((char[]){""}, '@')) ? result : "NULL");
    printf("reversed: '%s'\n", (result = reverseFromChar(NULL, '@')) ? result : "NULL");
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/1nsTGore9

Answer (score 1):

You should returned a pointer to the start of the reversed string in `reverse2nPart`. Here is a minimal modification of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* reverse2nPart(char* str, char ch) {    // changed here
    // Find the index of the specified character in the string
    char* chPos = strchr(str, ch);

    if (chPos != NULL) {
        // Calculate the length of the second part of the string
        int secondPartLen = strlen(chPos);

        // Reverse the second part of the string and save it in the original string
        for (int i = 0; i < secondPartLen / 2; i++) {
            char temp = chPos[i];
            chPos[i] = chPos[secondPartLen - 1 - i];
            chPos[secondPartLen - 1 - i] = temp;
        }
    }
    return chPos;           // changed here
}

int main() {
    char inputString[100];
    char ch;

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s", inputString);

    printf("Enter the character to substring the string: ");
    scanf(" %c", &ch); // Use a space before %c to consume the newline character

    char *reversed = reverse2nPart(inputString, ch);    // changed here

    // use reversed instead of inputstring from this point    
    printf("The reversed string is: %s\n", reversed);

    // Find the position of the specified character in the reversed string

    printf("The second character in the new reversed string is: %c\n", *(reversed + 1));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does that meet the requirements (save in original)?

Comment: @Deema: Yes it does because I have not changed that part...

Comment: Your function does not work in any border cases - for example, if the char was not found.

Comment: @0___________: I only made a minimal change to OP's code to output the expected value. I never pretended to fix any other problems...

Comment: @SergeBallesta IMO answer should point all issues found

Comment: @0___________: Agree... The reason why I upvoted yours :-) I probably was a bit too lazy.